# Not able to delete Jenkins job or build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to delete a Jenkins job via Remote Access api. I am doing a POST Request with the below url through my code. Manual delete through UI gives the same error.

https://JENKINS-URL.com/automationJob/doDelete.

**The POST Request is successful. But I am not able to delete the job because of this error**

As far as I analysed .nfs file inside my build is preventing the deletion..nfs file is created due to some open processes. I don't have access to Jenkins-CLI or ssh permission to check which process is keeping the .nfs file. So can someone point me in the right direction? Like can we execute some POST-BUILD Shell commands to close all the processes or delete the .nfs files that are open.

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/automationJob20181123161800281/builds/2/.nfs00000000023b265100000908: Device or resource busy
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:290)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:370)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:389)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:369)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:389)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:369)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteContentsRecursive(Util.java:389)
at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteRecursive(Util.java:369)
at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:347)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/automationJob20181123161800281'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
    at hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(Util.java:352)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.performDelete(AbstractItem.java:691)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.performDelete(AbstractProject.java:362)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.delete(AbstractItem.java:675)
    at hudson.model.Job.delete(Job.java:674)
    at hudson.model.AbstractItem.doDoDelete(AbstractItem.java:545)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:52)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
```